# How to make the row value as a link based on condition or column value

Tags: java, jsp, displaytag

I have a table that shows username and whether the user is administrator or not.

```
Username         Administrator     
user1            Yes
user2            No   
user3            No
user4            Yes
```

Here is the code of the table and it works fine.

```
<display:table name="${userTable}" class="users" uid ="row">
<display:column style="width: 8%" title="Username" property="username" maxLength="30" sortable="true" />
<display:column style="width: 4%" title="Administrator" property="usertype" sortable="true" />
</display:table>
```

I am trying to do is if the user is an administrator, the "Yes" will become a clickable link in the table that allows the administrator click to access to another page; whereas if the user is not an administrator, the "No" is just a simple text in the table.

I start to write some code, however, I think I misunderstand the usage of `<display:column>` and `<s:if>`. It is because I have two ideas to achieve it but all fail. So I am seeking someone to show me the right direction and correct my concept, please.

Here is my first idea.

```
<display:table name="${userTable}" class="users" uid ="row">
<display:column style="width: 8%" title="Username" property="username" maxLength="30" sortable="true" />
<s:if test="#session.USER_SESSSION_HANDLE.usertype.contains(\"Yes\")">
<display:column style="width: 4%" title="Administrator" property="usertype" sortable="true" />
</s:if>
</display:table>
```

When I run the code, the table does not have any changes, I mean in Administrator column, there is no clickable link if the value is "Yes", it is just a normal text. So my first idea is not a success.

I remove the previous code. Here is my second idea:

```
<display:table name="${userTable}" class="users" uid ="row">
<display:column style="width: 8%" title="Username" property="username" maxLength="30" sortable="true" />
<display:column style="width: 4%" title="Administrator" property="usertype" sortable="true" />

<display:column style="width: 5%" title="Link for Administrator" sortable="true">
<s:if test="#session.USER_SESSSION_HANDLE.usertype.contains(\"Yes\")">
<s:url var="editURL" namespace="/AdminLink" action="adminLink_edit">
<s:param name="recordId" value="%{#attr.row.recordId}" />
</s:url>
<s:a href="%{editURL}">It is a link</s:a>
</s:if>
<s:else>
<s:label>It is not a link</s:label>
</s:else>
</display:column>

</display:table>
```

In my second idea, I create another column to show whether it is a link or it is not a link. If it is a link, it should be clickable for further access, if it is not a link, it shows as a text.

When I run the code, the new column is created, but all rows display "It is a link" even the Administrator column shows "No" in the row.

I notice maybe I use user1 to access to the application, since user1 is administrator so its row should show "It is is a link", however, I don't understand why it will display to all rows.

Later I use user2(this username is not administrator) to access the system, I see all rows show "It is not a link", again, I don't understand why it effects to all rows. I guess because I use `<s:if test="#session.USER_SESSSION_HANDLE.usertype.contains(\"Yes\")">`? But why it will show the same result to all rows?

What I am trying to do is to make the "Yes" as a clickable link, and "No" is just a simple text. The sample table will look like the following. (Sorry I realize I cannot put [underline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117016/why-can-we-format-text-with-bold-and-italic-but-not-underline), so I put ** among "Yes"

```
Username         Administrator     
user1            **Yes**
user2            No   
user3            No
user4            **Yes**
```

Actually, I think my first idea can achieve but not success and I prefer not to use an extra column to show the link.

However, my second idea also not a success and I am not sure which part cause the problem.

Would someone let me know my mistake and give suggestion about how to make the row value as a link based on condition or column value, please? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figure it out. The solution is focus on my second idea which I will create another column for this part.

I need to change this code a little bit

```
<s:if test="#session.USER_SESSSION_HANDLE.usertype.contains(\"Yes\")">
```

It should be

```
<s:if test="#attr.row.usertype eq 'Yes'>
```

So the full code for that column will be something like this

```
<display:column style="width: 5%" title="Link for Administrator" sortable="true">
<s:if test="#attr.row.usertype eq 'Yes'>
<s:url var="editURL" namespace="/AdminLink" action="adminLink_edit">
<s:param name="recordId" value="%{#attr.row.recordId}" />
</s:url>
<s:a href="%{editURL}">It is a link</s:a>
</s:if>
<s:else>
<s:label>It is not a link</s:label>
</s:else>
</display:column>
```